# Why this variable lies on same address

Tags: c, linux

Here I have taken two local variables and printing the address of both.
I am getting both addresses is same how?

code is here:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char str[150];
    char arr[][15]={0};
    printf("---str:[%p]---arr0:[%p]---arr1:[%p]\n",str,arr[0],arr[1] );
}
```

and the output is:

```
cc tes.c 
root@asus-pc:~# ./a.out 
---str:[0x7fff669ac0a0]---arr0:[0x7fff669ac091]---arr1:[0x7fff669ac0a0]
root@asus-pc:~#
```

here the str and arr[1] address are the same.

please help me out.

thank you in advance

Comment: `arr[1]` is out-of-range.

Comment: In your program, `arr` is stored in memory before `str`. The compiler is under no obligation to use the same order as you in your program.

Comment: The line `arr[][15]={0};` is equivalent to `arr[1][15]={0};`, that is why `arr[1]` does not exist. The top-level array consists only of one element, so only `arr[0]` exists. Did you maybe intend to write `arr[0][1]` instead of `arr[1]`?

Comment: if arr[1] does not exist then how it's having an str address?

Comment: Referencing `arr[1]` invokes undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `char arr[][15]={0};`, the blank subscript leaves it to the compiler to calculate the number of elements. The single initial value initializes `arr[0][15]`, after which the compiler sets the remaining elements of `arr[0]` to zero. Since there are no initializers for `arr[1]`, the compiler sets the array size to 1 element, so `arr[0]` exists and `arr[1]` does not.

In the `printf`, `arr[1]` nominally refers to an array, so the compiler automatically converts it to a pointer to its first element, `&arr[1][0]`. While the behavior is not defined by the C standard, this nominally asks to compute where that element would be. Of course, if it existed, it would be immediately after the end of `arr[0]`. Since the compiler happened to place `str` just after `arr`, `str` is in the place that `arr[1][0]` would be, so the calculation produces the same address.

There are multiple reasons compiling and executing this same source code could produce different answers, including that the compiler may place `str` in a different location relative to `arr` and the fact that the behavior of using `arr[1]` is undefined means the compiler may transform it in unexpected ways during optimization.

However, the program can be changed to have (mostly) defined behavior by changing the `printf` to:

```
printf("---str:[%p]---arr0:[%p]---arr1:[%p]\n",
    (void *) str, (void *) &arr[0], (void *) &arr[1]);
```

Although `&arr[1]` appears to refer to a non-existent object, C 2018 6.5.3.2 3 results in it being treated as `arr+1`, and 6.5.6 8 allows us to calculate the address just beyond the last element in an array. So the behavior of this `printf` is sufficiently defined that it will print the indicated addresses.

In that case, the address printed for `str` will equal the address printed for `&arr[1]` if `str` happens to follow `arr` in memory.